# How to include file include at asp.net?

Tags: .aspxauth

I m developing a .asp site  for my a client. I m new at .asp, I know file including in php. Such:

```
<?php include("inc/contact.php"); ?>
```

But I try at asp this way.But Not work. I got a blank page. Now I would like to know: How to include file include at asp.net?

Answer (score 1):

To include any file at .asp, just type like bellow:

```
<!-- #include file="inc\contact.asp" -->
```

Importants matter is that, the Slash will left slash(\).